# Can I use telerik.dll in DotNetNuke custom modules for free

Tags: asp.net, telerik, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am building a dnn site where I want to use telerik controls.
Now the telerik.dll is included in DotNetNuke.
My question is can I reference this dll and use it in my modules for **free**?
(*I am building commercial site*)

Comment: no you can't. telerik is paid controls http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/telerik-dnn-partnership-qanda.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are allowed to use it for free in the modules inside your site, as long as you are using the DNN wrappers for the telerik controls.

You can't sell your custom modules though.

This is my interpretation of the 'Are there special requirements under which DNN Modules are developed using Telerik controls?' section of the link posted by Ravi

Comment: No I don't want to sell modules made with telerik controls. I wan't to use RadGrid to display data only on my dnn instance.

Comment: In this case you are allowed to use the DnnGrid (wrapper of the RadGrid) for free. There is a list of all the wrappers here http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Telerik-Wrappers.aspx

Comment: So as I understand this wrappers has all features of telerik controls and can be used the same way, right?

Comment: Yes almost all, I remember I was not able to find some functions relating to some Ajax stuff that telerik provides but in my case all the rest were more than enough to boost my app :)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, you can use the DNN controls that happen to use Telerik Controls without issue.  If you want to use a Telerik control in your module you need to own your own license of the Telerik tools.  It appears that if you purchase DNN Professional, you can have unlimited developers develop using Telerik controls.

The [Telerik DNN FAQ](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/telerik-dnn-partnership-qanda.aspx) will answer all your questions for you.